# Movie where a man transforms into a woman in space

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a movie years back. But not earlier than 2005.

Earth was dead and dried out and the last 3 men in the whole universe were left in a spaceship, and then suddenly one of the men literally transformed into a woman. So now there are 2 males and 1 female. The younger male believes that what happened to their colleague is a miracle and that he is the chosen one to impregnate the female in accordance with his religion (this boi is religious to the point that his beliefs are f*cked up). The other male tries to protect the one-who-became-female and help her explore his colleague's new body as a female.
The 2 males try to outdo each other but in the end both them die and the female is the only one left alive, who was impregnated by the religious psycho by forcing her.

Does anyone know the title of this movie?

I tried to search it but no luck. What I remember from the title of this movie is that it's only one word and it connects to the name of the one-who-became-female (and now I'm not sure about this part because I was 5 or 8 years old at that time).

Answer (score 19):

This is [*Paradox Alice*](https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/Paradox_Alice?id=4AS9wS0wOSQ&hl=en&gl=US) (2012).

> It's 2040, and a group of astronauts have been sent on a dangerous mission to retrieve water from Europa, one of the several moons orbiting the planet Jupiter. After narrowly escaping the moon to head back home, the team discovers that a nuclear war has left earth uninhabitable. **While the remaining male astronauts come to grips over their losses, one of the crew members spontaneously transforms into a woman** (in a scene that is as shocking as 1979's Alien). Each character tries to uncover the mystery of this horrific event. Was it an act of God, or a biological reaction for keeping the human race alive? As the men vie for the last female in existence, they begin to turn on one another. All of the questions come to a head in a shocking finale.

Comment: I can sleep in peace now 

Comment: @envie - Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as 'accepted'

Comment: Just when I think I found the strangest movie someone finds something stranger.